# Calculating a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I am writing a piece of software that must determine a transformation matrix that maps a set of $n$ points to another set of $n$ points, I would then use this matrix to modify the vertices of a large 2D mesh. However, I've been having some issues calculating it. I'm currently using the Eigen C++ mathematics library, it provides linear solvers for problems of the form $Ax = b$.

As an example problem, I try to solve this
$M \cdot T_1 = T_2$

where:

$T_1= \begin{bmatrix}1&2&2&1\\1&1&2&2\end{bmatrix}$

$T_2= \begin{bmatrix}1.5&3&2.5&2\\0.5&1.5&4&3.5\end{bmatrix}$

Which are simply the coordinates of a square ($T_1$) and a trapezium ($T_2$), illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YtkF.png).

Here is my current C++/Eigen solution for $M$:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2> M = ((T_1.transpose()).fullPivLu().solve(T_2.transpose())).transpose();
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here though, as the solver returns silly values. Admittedly, I'm not to clued up on this area, but if you could provide some guidance it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A linear operation with matrix $\pmatrix{a&b\\d&e}$ followed by a translation $\pmatrix{c\\f}$ is an affine transformation i.e., with equations of the form:

$$\tag{1}\cases{X=ax+by+c\\Y=dx+ey+f}$$

Your issue is to map a set of 4 points onto a set of 4 other points (all of them in general position).

You cannot do it (in general) using an affine tranform. Why that ?

It is due to the fundamental fact that an affine operator **preserves parallelism,** implying for example that the image of a square will be a square, a rectangle or a parallelogram, never a (general) trapezoid.

Your issue can be achieved using **projective transformations** (sometimes also called homographies) obtained by changing (1) into

$$\tag{2}\cases{X=\dfrac{ax+by+c}{gx+hx+i} \\ Y=\dfrac{dx+ey+f}{gx+hx+i}}$$

Please note that the denominators are identical.

Important: affine transformations are particular cases of projective transformations with $g=h=0$ and $i=1$.

Instead of requiring the calculation of 6 constants, you need to find 9 constants, but in fact 8 (there is a redundant degree of freedom due to the fact that one can multiply numerators and denominators by a same constant, thus vector $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i\}$ is defined up to multiplication by a constant.

This number of constants (8) is in perfect agreement with the fact that we have 8 constraints by imposing 4 points $(x_k,y_k)$ to be mapped onto 4 others $(X_k,Y_k)$, with, for each correspondance, one equation for the abscissa $X_k$ and one for the ordinate $Y_k$.

Many other things can be explained (points sent to infinity, etc...). The best for you is to ask for precise details.